# Oracle dead with unknown reason

Tags: oracle

Our Oracle database dies from time to time. When I look into the log in the alert, it shows following Exception:

```
Exception [type: SIGSEGV, Address not mapped to object] [ADDR:0xFFFFFFFEAA7DD0E0] [PC:0x8213123, kslgetl()+111] [flags: 0x0, count: 1]
ORA-07445: [kslgetl()+111] [SIGSEGV] [ADDR:0xFFFFFFFEAA7C58C0] [PC:0x8213123] [Address not mapped to object] []
DDE: Problem Key 'ORA 7445 [kslgetl()+111]' was completely flood controlled (0x6)
Further messages for this problem key will be suppressed for up to 10 minutes
Errors in file /home/oracle/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/orcl/SDH/trace/SDH_p104_2581.trc  (incident=82376):
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [ksl_invalid_latch], [kslges], [0x2AFF2F2D8], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Contact oracle customer support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We find the problem is caused by out of memory. When there is not enough memory, Oracle will behave like this or cause the OS system to hang. We believe it is the stored procedure that caused the problem.